# Adding a column to the view which shows the date in format YYYYMM

Tags: db2, view

In the following view, I want to add a column (not alter the view) named say "ABC" which shows the date in format `YYYYMM` (no date, only year and month). How can I do that? I am using db2.

```
create view VIEW_IRS1 as Select 
MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID
, Atr.Ssn_Tx
, Names.First_Na
, Names.Middle_Na
, Names.Last_Na
, Reff.Ref_Cd_Desc_Tx Suffix_Na
,'FALSE' AS "Request Title II Monthly Income Verification"

From Hix.T_Enrt En 
Inner Join Hix.T_Prsn_Enrt Pe On En.Enrt_Id = Pe.Enrt_Id And En.Enrt_Status_Cd In 
(428,439, 430 ) And Pe.Active_In = 'Y' And (Pe.Retro_In Is Null Or Pe.Retro_In = 'N') 

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Aptc Ap On En.Enrt_Id = Ap.Enrt_Id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Prsn_Addl_Attr Atr On Pe.Prsn_Mbrsh_Id = Atr.Prsn_Mbrsh_Id

Left Outer Join
(                   
    Select nAc.Prsn_mbrsh_Id,  First_Na , Middle_Na , Last_Na, Suffix_Cd From 
    Hix.T_Prsn_Name Na, Hix.t_prsn_mbrsh_prsn_name_ac nAc
    where na.prsn_name_id = nAc.prsn_Name_Id
) Names On Pe.prsn_mbrsh_id = Names.prsn_mbrsh_id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Ref_Data Reff On Names.Suffix_Cd = Reff.Ref_Data_Id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_Ref_Data Re On Atr.GENDER_CD = Reff.Ref_Data_Id

Left Outer Join Hix.T_PRSN_MBRSH MBR on MBR.PRSN_MBRSH_ID=Pe.PRSN_ENRT_ID;
```

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: I have found the solution. The logic to print date in YYYYMM format is :

select YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) 
from sysibm.sysdummy1 
Thanks guys :)

Comment: You wouldn't even need sysdummy1. Just do a select column1, column2,....... (YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE)) CURRENT_MONTH_DATE from view_irs1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows here, since you don't specify, but this will probably also work on the other platforms.)

You don't have to do funky date math, there is a built-in function [`VARCHAR_FORMAT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-179) that will do it for you:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMM')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```